# No breakpoint stop in C++ part of Python/C++ code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, remote-debugging

I am working with Python / C++ debugger extension in VSCode. I used it in Windows without issues. Now I tried to transfer my configuration to WSL2. I modified `launch.json` to use proper paths to my Python environment (see below). I added `-g` to `CMakeLists.txt` with `add_compile_options(-g)` as proposed in another question on the similar topic. I use Debug, not Release version. `make all`  completes without an error and creates a `pybind11` bindings, which is exactly what I would like to debug.

However, the debugger does not enter into C++ part of the code how it did on Windows. Nothing crashes, the Python debugger works as expected, C++ gdb attach starts as well. However, neither breakpoints nor step-by-step entering in C++ part works. There are multiple threads in gdb attach as shown below, not sure if that is the issue.

[image]

`launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PythonDebug",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "main.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/python/",
            
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "/home/user/venv/bin/python", /* My virtual env */
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "PythonCppDebug",
            "type": "pythoncpp",
            "request": "launch",
            "pythonConfig": "custom",
            "pythonLaunchName": "PythonDebug",
            "cppConfig": "custom", 
            "cppAttachName": "(gdb) Attach", 
        }
    ]
}
```